# How to set default value for Wicket DropDownChoice

Tags: wicket

can someone give me an advice, how to set default value to Wicket DropDownChoice?

I have this code, and I need to select value to proper TabType

```
DropDownChoice<TabType> tabTypeDropDownChoice = new DropDownChoice<TabType>("tabType", new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "tabType"), tabTypeDao.findAll());
            tabTypeDropDownChoice.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            item.add(tabTypeDropDownChoice);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just set the model object to the desired value:

```
TabType defaultTabType = //get default value
DropDownChoice<TabType> tabTypeDropDownChoice = new DropDownChoice<TabType>("tabType", new PropertyModel(item.getModel(), "tabType"), tabTypeDao.findAll());
tabTypeDropDownChoice.setOutputMarkupId(true);
tabTypeDropDownChoice.setModelObject​(defaultTabType);
item.add(tabTypeDropDownChoice);
```